# Why java DocumentBuilder need 2 steps to be created, not 1 step?

Tags: java, dom, factory, document, builder

Using DOM's javax.xml.parsers I've to write code like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

I checked the jdk source code of it:

```
public static DocumentBuilderFactory newInstance() {
    return FactoryFinder.find(
            /* The default property name according to the JAXP spec */
            DocumentBuilderFactory.class, // "javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"
            /* The fallback implementation class name */
            "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
}
```

It's weird to me:

1. The factory mode is usually have a static factory, then use factory.create to generate a "product". Is it a JAXP protocol principle to have a factory?
2. As long as this document factory is part of java sdk, why it still has to "FactoryFinder.find()" to find some classes that could generate such a factory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is used to allow changing factory implementation via configuration if for some reason you need to use custom factory (for example if you faced bug in JDK standard factory).

```
* Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory.
 * This configuration file is in standard <code>java.util.Properties
 * </code> format and contains the fully qualified name of the
 * implementation class with the key being the system property defined
 * above.
```

Comment: I searched my $JAVA_HOME, didn't find a lib/jaxp.properties. My question is, if DocumentBuilderFactory newInstance() refers to a fixed class name, how could it be configured?

Comment: @HindForsum `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` is  a default fallback which will be used if no other implementation provided either in properties class or using `-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=...` method.

Comment: It's odd that as long as the class itself is "DocumentBuilderFactory", how can it "not able to find" DocumentBuilderFactory class itself, and fallback to apache implementation? Thanks.

Comment: `DocumentBuilderFactory` is an interface and that is an actual implementation that does the stuff. That is why JVM looks for implementation of an interface and falls back to Apache's implementation.